# BeautifulSoup trips up on meta tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

I have this function to read saved HTML files saved on the computer:

```
 def get_doc_ondrive(self,mypath):
  the_file = open(mypath,"r")
  line = the_file.readline()
  if(line != "")and (line!=None):
   self.soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
  else:
   print "Something is wrong with line:\n\n%r\n\n" % line
   quit()
  print "\t\t------------ line: %r ---------------\n" % line
  while line != "":
   line = the_file.readline()
   print "\t\t------------ line: %r ---------------\n" % line
   if(line != "")and (line!=None):
    print "\t\t\tinner if executes: line: %r\n" % line
    self.soup.feed(line)
  self.get_word_vector()
  self.has_doc = True
```

Doing `self.soup = BeautifulSoup(open(mypath,"r"))` returns None, but feeding it line by line at least crashes and gives me something to look at.

I edited the functions listed by the traceback in BeautifulSoup.py and sgmllib.py

When I try to run this, I get:

```
me@GIGABYTE-SERVER:code$ python test_docs.py
in sgml.finish_endtag

in _feed: inDocumentEncoding: None, fromEncoding: None, smartQuotesTo: 'html'
in UnicodeDammit.__init__: markup: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
in UnicodeDammit._detectEncoding: xml_data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
in sgmlparser.feed: rawdata: '', data: u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n' self.goahead(0)
        ------------ line: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' ---------------
        ------------ line: '<html dir="ltr" class="client-js ve-not-available" lang="en"><head>\n' ---------------
            inner if executes: line: '<html dir="ltr" class="client-js ve-not-available" lang="en"><head>\n'
in sgmlparser.feed: rawdata: u'', data: '<html dir="ltr" class="client-js ve-not-available" lang="en"><head>\n' self.goahead(0)
in sgmlparser.goahead: end: 0,rawdata[i]: u'<', i: 0,literal:0
in sgmlparser.parse_starttag: i: 0, __starttag_text: None, start_pos: 0, rawdata: u'<html dir="ltr" class="client-js ve-not-available" lang="en"><head>\n'
in sgmlparser.goahead: end: 0,rawdata[i]: u'<', i: 61,literal:0
in sgmlparser.parse_starttag: i: 61, __starttag_text: None, start_pos: 61, rawdata: u'<html dir="ltr" class="client-js ve-not-available" lang="en"><head>\n'
        ------------ line: '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n' ---------------
            inner if executes: line: '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n'
in sgmlparser.feed: rawdata: u'', data: '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n' self.goahead(0)
in sgmlparser.goahead: end: 0,rawdata[i]: u'<', i: 0,literal:0
in sgmlparser.parse_starttag: i: 0, __starttag_text: None, start_pos: 0, rawdata: u'<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n'
in sgml.finish_starttag: tag: u'meta', attrs: [(u'http-equiv', u'content-type'), (u'content', u'text/html; charset=UTF-8')]
in start_meta: attrs: [(u'http-equiv', u'content-type'), (u'content', u'text/html; charset=UTF-8')] declaredHTMLEncoding: u'UTF-8'
in _feed: inDocumentEncoding: u'UTF-8', fromEncoding: None, smartQuotesTo: 'html'
in UnicodeDammit.__init__: markup: None
in UnicodeDammit._detectEncoding: xml_data: None
```

and the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_docs.py", line 28, in <module>
    newdoc.get_doc_ondrive(testeee)
  File "/home/jddancks/Capstone/Python/code/pkg/vectors/DOCUMENT.py", line 117, in get_doc_ondrive
    self.soup.feed(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 139, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 298, in parse_starttag
    self.finish_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 348, in finish_starttag
    self.handle_starttag(tag, method, attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 385, in handle_starttag
    method(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1618, in start_meta
    self._feed(self.declaredHTMLEncoding)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1172, in _feed
    smartQuotesTo=self.smartQuotesTo, isHTML=isHTML)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1776, in __init__
    self._detectEncoding(markup, isHTML)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1922, in _detectEncoding
    '^<\?.*encoding=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*\?>').match(xml_data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

so this line

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n
```

is somehow causing a null string to be parsed in UnicodeDammit. Why is this happening?

Comment: why are you not using bs4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read through [the source](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/3.2/view/head:/BeautifulSoup.py) and I think I understand the problem. Essentially, here’s how BeautifulSoup thinks things are supposed to go:

1. You call `BeautifulSoup` with the entire markup.
2. It sets `self.markup` to that markup.
3. It calls `_feed` on itself, which resets the document and parses it in the initially-detected encoding.
4. While feeding itself, it finds a `meta` tag that states a different encoding.
5. To use this new encoding, it calls `_feed` on itself again, which reparses `self.markup`.
6. After the first `_feed` as well as the `_feed` it recursed into has finished, it sets `self.markup` to `None`. (After all, we’ve parsed everything now; `<sarcasm>`who could *ever* need the original markup any more?`</sarcasm>`)

But the way you’re using it:

1. You call `BeautifulSoup` with the first line of the markup.
2. It sets `self.markup` to the first line of the markup and calls `_feed`.
3. `_feed` sees no interesting `meta` tag on the first line, so finishes successfully.
4. The constructor thinks we’re done parsing, so it sets `self.markup` back to `None` and returns.
5. You call `feed` on the `BeautifulSoup` object, which goes straight to the `SGMLParser.feed` implementation, which is not overridden by `BeautifulSoup`.
6. It sees an interesting `meta` tag and calls `_feed` to parse the document in this new encoding.
7. `_feed` goes trying to construct a `UnicodeDammit` object with `self.markup`.
8. It explodes, since `self.markup` is `None`, since it thought it was only going to be called during that little chunk of time in the constructor of `BeautifulSoup`.

Moral of the story is that `feed` is an unsupported way of sending input to `BeautifulSoup`. You have to pass it all the input at once.

As for why `BeautifulSoup(open(mypath, "r"))` returns `None`, I’ve no idea; I don’t see a `__new__` defined on `BeautifulSoup`, so it seems like it *has to* return a `BeautifulSoup` object.

All that said, you *might* want to look into using BeautifulSoup 4 rather than 3. [Here’s the porting guide.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4) In order to support Python 3, it had to remove the dependency on `SGMLParser`, and I wouldn’t be surprised if during that part of the rewrite whatever bug you’re encountering was fixed.

Comment: IDK what it is but switching to BS4 did the trick. Thank you sir I think your answer will help others in the future googling the problem.